# Phonegap: When keyboard is closed by losing focus elements with position fixed are displayed wrong

Tags: ios, cordova

I start from scratch with a new phonegap app and only add an input element, a button and header and footer with `position: fixed`.

The problem that I have is: 
I have focus on my input (and keyboard is visible) and click on button (that do nothing). In that moment input lose focus and the keyboard is hidden, but all my fixed elements (header and footer) are displayed in the middle of the screen for half a second and after that go to correct place.

If I click on `Done` from keyboard everything is ok.

You can see in this gif my problem:

- First time I click on `AAA` button => Here is the problem
- Second time I click on `Done` from keyboard => Everything is working ok.

[image]

This is the css for my header (similar for footer div)

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #003777; }
```

And in my html I only add a `div` with class `header` from above, similar for footer and `<input type='text'>` and `<button type='button'>AAA</button>`

So nothing special, just for testing this problem.

The problem is only on iOS devices, tested on iOS 9.